# PCA to decorrelate and classify timeseries

Tags: time-series, classification, pca

I have a labeled dataset where each subject belongs to one of two classes `A` or `B`, with `A` being the majority. Each subject, has 6 **independent** different time-series, each of length `t`. I would like to classify each subject as belonging to either class.

1. So, one way to look at it, is that I have 6 **independent** features per
   subject, where each feature is a vector in R^`t`.
2. Another way to look at it, is as a `n x 6*t` matrix, where each
   subject has `6t` many *correlated* features.

I want to try PCA on the time-series for dimensionality reduction but more importantly to decorrelate, but am unsure how to proceed. PCA gives me a set of principal (eigen) components and values. What exactly would I apply the PCA on? Do I:

1. separate out my data into 6 different `n x t` blocks, each one representing one independent feature and PCA on that? **How would I classify after having performed the multiple PCAs?** What would be my 'features' in that case? The values? The components?
2. PCA on the entire `n x 6t` matrix and classify in the transformed space?

Comment: Try to use Independent Component Analysis to decorrelate your time-series.

Comment: If you wish to analyze trends, seasonality or noise component in your time-series, take a look at Singular Spectrum Analysis (SSA).

Comment: For time-series classification, I found Global Alignment Kernels to be working very well http://www.icml-2011.org/papers/489_icmlpaper.pdf. It can classify also multiple time-series at once. The code is also available on author's website.

Comment: thanks! I'd like to try and understand my questions from first principles though. Why use iCA?

Comment: The property of ICA is just that - decorrelate the signals in time-series.